# Split Video to smaller parts by Size in C#

Tags: c#, video, split

I want to split my videos (my videos from 10GB To 100GB) to smaller part by size (not time).
For example, convert a 20GB video to 10 * 2GB Video
And each of these videos can be played and used.

I used this [example](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/read-large-file-into-a-byte-array-with-chunks-csharp/) but the videos made are not playable

```cs
private static void ReadFile(string filePath)
{
    const int MAX_BUFFER = 1048576; //1MB 
    byte[] buffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER];
    int bytesRead;
    int noOfFiles = 0;
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
    {
        while ((bytesRead = bs.Read(buffer, 0, MAX_BUFFER)) != 0) //reading 1mb chunks at a time
        {
            noOfFiles++;
            //Let's create a small size file using the data. Or Pass this data for any further processing.

            File.WriteAllBytes($"Test{noOfFiles}.txt", buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

I also saw this:
[Splitting a video in four files in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43865533/splitting-a-video-in-four-files-in-c-sharp)
but this cut a video by time/sec.

So how can I do this with C# ?

Comment: The example you have doesn't understand what the file is. It just splits the data into chunks without understanding it. An analogy would be a human cutting an A4 document into paragraphs, vs a shredder just making cuts at predefined intervals (in mm or inches).

Comment: Perhaps you could use ffmpeg (I would): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38259544/using-ffmpeg-to-split-video-files-by-size

Comment: Easiest is probably to split the file at the closest available i-frame. But that require tools that can unpack/repack the video-file.  You could also re-compress the video, but then you have to determine the desired quality and average bitrate to reach that quality somehow.